# Python function call inside single class

Tags: python

I want both these function inside the same class math. using math 
class object. I can call both these functions.And I also want fibonacii  series comes inside array.

```
#fibonacii series of a no using recursion
def fib(n):
    if n<=1:
        return n
    else:
        return (fib(n-1) + fib(n-2))

n = int(input("Enter number of terms:"))
print("Fibonacii series are: ")
for i in range (n):
    print(fib(i))

#for factorial
n=int(input("Enter the no to find factorial: "))
def facts(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    if n>=1:
       return n * facts(n-1)
print("The facatorial of a given no",str(n),"is:",facts(n))
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried and where did you face problem. Please visit here to see how to create classes in python https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: What I actually want. I want to create a single class for these 2 functions. And these 2 functions inside the same class. I want to call these functions using the class object.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a class with static methods:

```
class Fibonacii(object):
   def __init__(self):
      # this is the constructor you can initialize stuff here if required
      # if not just pass it like in this example
      pass

   @staticmethod
   def fib(n):
    if n<=1:
        return n
    else:
        return (Fibonacii.fib(n-1) + Fibonacii.fib(n-2))

   @staticmethod
   def facts(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    if n>=1:
       return n * Fibonacii.facts(n-1)
```

static method have the advantage that they can be used without creating an object of that class. So in your script you can do:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   n = int(input("Enter number of terms:"))
   print("Fibonacii series are: ")
   for i in range (n):
       print(Fibonacii.fib(i))

   #for factorial
   n=int(input("Enter the no to find factorial: "))
   print("The facatorial of a given no",str(n),"is:",Fibonacii.facts(n))
```

The part after main is the part of the script that is being executed if it is the main script. Notice that the class is never used to create a object. But it is used to save your two functions and can be used to call them.